# How do I enter these triplets into MuseScore?

Tags: notation, engraving, musescore, tuplet

[image]

I'm a total beginner with all things music theory, so I figured I'd ask.

I'm trying to enter this into MuseScore, but the triplets in the last two bars are confusing me. If I try to enter them I get these extra rests. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Edit:
I am able to make desired triplets if I make some new measures in 2/2 and 4/4 time. But I'm wondering, why can't I make such a triplet in measure 52? 52 is in 2/2 time. All I can think of is that MuseScore doesn't like the staves changing time signatures separately. Any idea how to work around this? FYI: I am using MuseScore 3. I realize this is out of date, but I can't stand the way dynamics work in MuseScore 4.

[image]

Comment: I am equally confused. Entering these triplets should be straightforward: Select duraction 1/2 and press Ctrl+3 to enter a tuplet of total length 1/2. Then enter the first three notes. Then again select duration 1/2, press Ctrl+3, and enter the second group of notes. Could you possibly share with us step by step how you enter these tuplets, and when the problem starts to appear?

Comment: I bet the problem has something to do with the fact that each staff changes time signature at a different moment.

Comment: That looks like what a less-than-smart DAW will do if the notes & score prefs aren't quantised

Comment: The software thinks you need an extra 1/16 + 1/64 + 1/256 + 1/1024 ≈ 1/12 of a measure in the "triplet tempo", which is equivalent to an extra 1/8 note in the "base tempo".  No idea why, though.

Comment: As Elements in Space implies, MuseScore may not be able to handle Strauss's unusual combination of time signatures. I wonder what Strauss thought he gained by writing the soprano in different time signatures from the orchestra here. (In the 2nd to 4th bars of the excerpt.)

Comment: The problem seems to occur when you have two different time signatures at once and in one them, add a second voice (like you did in m. 51). For some reason the program allocates the wrong amount of "rest space" (perhaps confused by the time signature mix). Just play around a little and you should be able to correct the wrong spacing.

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is a basic quarter-note triplet where the first two quarter notes of the triplet are combined into a single half-note value.

MuseScore's triplet function is based on making a triplet out of whatever note or rest value is currently highlighted. As such, because this is a triplet that takes up two quarter-note beats, you'll want to first highlight a half note (or half rest) before clicking the triplet option; note that the half rest is highlighted blue while I click triplet:

[image]

With the triplet now created, click on the half note to enter that first half note of the triplet:

[image]

The rest should be relatively straightforward to reach what you want:

[image]

Comment: I'm doing just that and it doesn't work. It works if I do that in a different measure, but for some reason not in the one I'm trying to do it in. Just to see what would happen, I tried making some measures in 4/4 and 2/2. When I made the triplets in those measures it worked perfectly. So I'm wondering, is the problem the fact that the staves in the score change time signatures at different times?

Comment: @AdrianD are you in note-inputted mode?